# Upload CSV file to Google Cloud Storage using Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I need to automate uploading local csv file into Google Cloud storage bucket in Python. Which Python library can I use? Any sample code would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use the google python client api to upload files to google cloud storage.

First, install the api client as follows.

```
>pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

Then, enable api authentication to get application default credentials.

```
>gcloud beta auth application-default login
```

Below is a sample code which uploads a local file to google cloud storage using application default credentials.

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = discovery.build('storage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

filename = 'C:\\MyFiles\\sample.csv'
bucket = 'my_bucket'

body = {'name': 'dest_file_name.csv'}
req = service.objects().insert(bucket=bucket, body=body, media_body=filename)
resp = req.execute()
```

This will upload the file inside my_bucket. The full google storage url for the uploaded file would be gs://my_bucket/dest_file_name.csv

Answer (score 2):

Another way is as shown in this [link](https://riptutorial.com/google-cloud-storage/example/28256/upload-files-using-python).

First, connect to cloud

```
from gcloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
```

Then select the bucket and choose remote filename

```
bucket = client.get_bucket('<your-bucket-name>')
blob = bucket.blob('remote_file.txt')
```

Finally, upload the local file. I prefer the following way but there are alternative ways.

```
blob.upload_from_filename('local_file_txt')
```

If you have a variable, the above line requires you to write your variable into disk, then upload which may not be the best way. Instead you can directly write to the blob from a string.

```
blob.upload_from_string('this is test content!')
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to import any library.
You can create a POST request to the method's /upload URI and add the query parameter

```
uploadType=media
```

For example:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/myBucket/o?uploadType=media
```

Add a name query parameter to identify which resource the upload is associated with.

For example, to specify that an object's name is myObject:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/myBucket/o?uploadType=media&name=myObject
```

Add the file's data to the request body.
Add the following HTTP headers:

- Content-Type. Set to the MIME media type of the object being uploaded.
- Content-Length. Set to the number of bytes you are uploading. This heading is not required if you are using chunked transfer encoding.

Example upload:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/myBucket/o?uploadType=media&name=myObject HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: [csv]
Content-Length: [NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_FILE]
Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]

[DATA]
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use pandas library. follow the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
tobq = pd.read_csv("local.csv")
pd.io.gbq(tobq, "big_query_table_name", "project_name", private_key="big_query_private_key.json")
```

Comment: Your answer is not GCS related, but about BigQuery.